# Using Administration Dashboard with Declarative Authorization and Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, administration, declarative-authorization

I use Declarative Authorization and Authlogic and now wants to create a dashboard for the administration. About ActiveScaffold will be an overview of the different controllers are shown.

However, I have the problem that I can admin no "admin rights" to the subfolders 
app/controllers/admin/admin_controller. How can I do that?

Currently my Authorization_rules.rb looks like this:

```
authorization do
    role :admin do
      includes :guest
      has_permission_on :admin,     :to => [:index]
    end
end
```

But that does not work! Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: I solve this some minutes later.
If you want to add rules for subfolders you must something like this:
rule for admin/admin_controller:

role :admin do
  has_permissions_on :admin_admin, :to=>[:index]
end

Comment: good job. btw it's perfectly correct to post your own solution as an answer and accept it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

I solve this some minutes later. 
If you want to add rules for subfolders you must something like this: 
rule for admin/admin_controller:

```
role :admin do 
  has_permissions_on :admin_admin, :to=>[:index] 
end
```